# Apply VBA code in ribbon button to renamed Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, filenames

I have a ribbon button which once clicked will open a dialogue box to let me attach a file to my spreadsheet. I recorded a macro and edited the code with the help of Google. It works.

The filename regularly gets updated when changes are made. Once renamed the code breaks.

If I understand, the code is linked to both the filename and the worksheet name. The worksheet won't change. Is there any way to make the code independent of the filename?

The Excel file is on a shared drive that others can view/edit, so it would be nice to make a file attaching button, that anyone can use.

The code is in Excel on the code sheet for the worksheet tab:

```vb
Sub AttachEmail()

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
    .Title = "Choose File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=FileSelected, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False).Select
End Sub
```

It's a macro enabled workbook. There's a version in the file name "...v1a" and people rename this v1b, v1c, v2a.

If I close it, rename it, then open it. I click the button to "Enable content". When I use my button I get an error message

> Sorry we couldn't find <path+file name>. Is it possible it was moved, renamed, or deleted?

Is there a way I can use this ribbon button without having to manually remove the macro and reattach it every time I rename the file?

Comment: what are the issues with your code?

Comment: Just that if I rename my excel file then the code no longer works. To my knowledge the code is linked to the previous file name.  I was hoping there was a way to automatically resolve this issue because the file name gets updated frequently and by different users

Comment: There are lots of ways a code "doesn't work" or "is broken". To help you it's important to know what's up. The first thing I can think of in this case is that macros will be disabled when you rename the file?

Comment: i test and the code will work after renaming excel file, is it a macro enabled file (.xlsm)? how do other ones rename it (keep extension)? also, when you open renamed file, can you see its vb code in Visual Basic Editor under its specific sheet?

Comment: It's a macro enabled workbook. There's a version in the file name I.e "...v1a" and people just rename this I.e v1b,v1c,v2a.

Comment: If I closed it, renamed it, then opened it. I would click the button to "Enable content" . When I use my button I get an error message stating "sorry we couldn't find <path+file name>. Is it possible it was moved,renamed, or deleted?"

Comment: does the value of <path+file name> you read in the error message make sense to you? if you debug your code which line is highlighted?

Comment: No line of code is highlighted. I just get that error message. The VB sheet the code is saved in is linked to the name of the file. And when the file is renamed, the code is still linked to the old name

Comment: so how do you write your vb code? it must be part of your excel file itself.

Comment: what kind of button do you have on your sheet? an ActiveX one or a Form one?

Comment: I tried to create an example file to upload for you guys but I screwed up since my macro works fine on that example file....

Comment: The button itself is on the Ribbon. You can create one by going into Options, customise the ribbon, and add your tab/group/macro

Comment: Right now I don't quite understand why I can't replicate my error message for you guys

Comment: Ok, for the example file, to run the macro, I go into Developer -> Macros -> and then run my selected macro. This works. I found the error comes from the button I created in the ribbon

Comment: The question is there a way I can use this button I put on the ribbon without having to manually remove the macro and reattach it every time I rename the file?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Just ran into that problem. I'm doing a workbook for people who are less computer savy, so having shortcut for the macros is important :/

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862446.aspx) for the FileDialog object:

> Each host application can only create a single instance of the
>   FileDialog object. Therefore, many of the properties of the FileDialog
>   object persist even when you create multiple FileDialog objects.
>   Therefore, make sure that you set all of the properties appropriately
>   for your purpose before you display the dialog box.

I suspect that if your Excel instance isn't closing, one of those properties is persisting (and giving your error the second time you use it).

The most likely candidate based on the message you're receiving is the [`InitialFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863092.aspx) (my emphasis):

> If you specify an invalid path, the last-used path is used. ***A message
>   warns users when an invalid path is used***.

I'd add the following line of code to ensure that you always will always get a valid value:

```
With myFile
    .Title = "Choose File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    'Add this.
    .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path  'Or ThisWorkbook.Path
```

Note that if the workbook hasn't already been saved, this will default to the user's documents folder.

Comment: It sounded like a great solution but I tried and still got the same error sadly. (I tried both This and Active Workbook, and reattached the macro button on the ribbon). (See my other comments on why I reattached)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out but the search for it wasn't fun so since this was the first link to pop up, I'll answer here and maybe help others to figure it out faster.

The problem is that excel save the macro action as 'file_path/file_name.xlms!macro_name'. So the solution is to export the ribbon customization by going to 'customize ribbon' then 'import/export' then 'export all customization'. Then open that with a text editor. Optional: make a new xml file so you can format it in a readable way. Then, for each of your macro, find the mso:tab and mso:group it's in and change

```
<mso:button
  idQ="x1:file_path/file_name.xmls!ThisWorkbook.macro_name_0"
  label="Macro Label" imageMso="ImageMso"
  onAction="file_path/file_name.xmls!ThisWorkbook.macro_name"
  visible="true" />
```

for

```
<mso:button
  idQ="x1:ThisWorkbook.macro_name_0"
  label="Macro Label" imageMso="ImageMso"
  onAction="ThisWorkbook.macro_name"
  visible="true" />
```

*Note: 'ThisWorkbook.' may or may not be there depending on where you saved your macro. I had saved it in "ThisWorkbook' and not a module or a sheet.*